# React is messing up HTML elements when using Ternary Operator for conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

When a user is not true, React is displaying the "signin" div, but when user is true React is displaying the "user-profile" div's children inside the "signin" div. Why is this happening?

I tried a couple of ways to fix this, but this error is not going away. Please help if anyone know how to solve this error.

```
{user ?
                                (
                                    <div className="user-profile">
                                        <div>
                                            <i className="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
                                            <span style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>{"Hi, " + user.firstname}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="user-profile-menu">
                                            <ul className="menu-list">
                                                <li className="menu-item">
                                                    <i className="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
                                                    <a href="#">Your Profile</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li className="menu-item">
                                                    <i className="bi bi-cart4"></i>
                                                    <a href="#">Your Orders</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li className="menu-item">
                                                    <i className="bi bi-geo-alt-fill"></i>
                                                    <a href="#">Manage Address</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li className="menu-item">
                                                    <i class="bi bi-person-x-fill"></i>
                                                    <a href="#">Sign Out</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                                : (
                                    <div className="signin">
                                        <a href="/auth/signin" className="signin-btn">
                                            <i className="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
                                            <span style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>Sign In</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            }
```

Comment: Don’t you need a space between “user” and “?” ?

Comment: Can you put that in a sandbox?

Comment: You have to have a bug somewhere else, the logic is relentless :)

Comment: OK, I put code in codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that `user` is being set outside of your component. My hypothesis is that your component is not actually seeing the update to `user`, and thus rendering incorrectly.

Make sure that `user` is part of your component's state, that way your component will update when `user` changes.

Comment: You're right, and Thanks, I have solved my error.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sunset-7wrh1?file=/src/MiniFacebook.jsx). When you pass user null you will see signIn option, when you provide a user you will see profile details page.

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sunset-7wrh1?file=/src/MiniFacebook.jsx